# Changing font size of UI in Windows 8 Mail app

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-8-mail-app

Is it possible to decrease the font size of UI in the Windows 8 mail app? The folder list is huge (I think for touch purpose) and wastes a lot of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do so.

Comment: I think you're right. There is no such option in Personalization and no answer in Google :)

Comment: As Jeff said on his blog: "The default Surface mail application is an embarrassment and everyone associated with it should be fired."

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I do not believe it is possible to do this.

A workaround may be using the Magnifier tool which you can activate by using <kbd>Win +</kbd> or <kbd>Win -</kbd>

Comment: Magnifier doesn't go less than 100%. So I don't think this helps.

Comment: You can only increase size with the magnifier tool. 100% is the minimum